# Unable to select text in Word

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

I am running Word on Mac OS Monterey v12.0.1.  I have updated to the latest version of Word.

For some reason I am unable to select text the normal way.  If I do Shift+click then I can sometimes select what I want.

Please help!

Comment: First thing to do is get off the horribly buggy 12.0.1.

Comment: You mean you want to double click to select the text?

Comment: @Lee no that works, problem is highlighting multiple lines of text

Comment: @BAR  What about SHIFT+up/down  to highlight multiple lines. And  shift+left/right to highlight left  and right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try updating MacOS

I had the problem you mention, though under MacOS 12.3 and Word 16.62 Home/Student. Just yesterday I updated MacOS to 12.5 on my MacBook Pro M1 Pro and now I can select text just fine.  I believe the problem was either a MacOS problem, or, more likely, an incorrect interaction between Word and MacOS.